# Uninstalling system center 2007 result on clients

Tags: system-center

Will the installed software (Office etc.) be removed from client computers when I uninstall System Center Server 2007 (which deployed the software to them)?

I don't want all of the deployed software to suddenly disappear just because I remove the server software!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, software installed by SCCM-client doesn't suddenly disappear from client computers when SCCM Primary Site is uninstalled. You'll need to advertise the removal of program to uninstall software from targeted computers.

If you want to completely remove all SCCM-related programs and not reattach all SCCM-clients to other sites, then remove first all SCCM-clients by entering the following from the command prompt on the client computer:

`CCMSetup.exe /uninstall`

If you want to uninstall the SCCM-client from many computers, then you may create a package using Configuration Manager software distribution that will distribute above command to targeted computers.

Use the log file CCMSetup.log in the `%windir%\system32\ccmsetup` folder on the client computer to verify that the SCCM-client has been removed succesfully.

To uninstall a Configuration Manager primary site, you can use the Configuration Manager Setup Wizard. You can either start the wizard from the installation source files or you can use the Add or Remove Programs applet in the Control Panel by selecting the installation to uninstall.

If you want to reassign SCCM-clients to another site, then to avoid orphaning clients or child sites of the site to be uninstalled, you'll need to ensure that any child sites have been reattached to other site and any assigned clients have been reconfigured to be managed by a different primary site.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can safely remove SCCM without affecting client computers; just be sure to uninstall its agent software on them, otherwise it will become *quite* unhappy when it will not find its server anymore.